# Find $\frac{x^2}{y^2}$ + $\frac{y^2}{x^2}$

Tags: fractions

If $\frac{x}{y}$ + $\frac{y}{x}$ = 3 Find $\frac{x^2}{y^2}$ + $\frac{y^2}{x^2}$

Any Ideas on how to begin ?

Comment: Hint try to solve the equation $t+t^{-1} = 3$ where $t = y/x$

Comment: A general problem-solving strategy: what could you do to the given to get what you want? Here, the obvious thing to try is squaring, since doing so will generate something that more closely resembles the expression you're after. Sometimes the obvious thing to try doesn't work, but one can always hope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} = 3 &\Longrightarrow \left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 = 9 \\
&\Longrightarrow \frac{x^2}{y^2} + \frac{y^2}{x^2} = 9-2=7
\end{align*}

Comment: Why was 2 subtracted from nine?

Comment: Since $\displaystyle 2\cdot \frac{x}{y}  \cdot \frac{y}{x} = 2$.

Comment: I don't get it still.Can you explain a little bit more

Comment: It is just the use of perfect square formula. Here is the thing: \begin{align*} &\quad\quad\left( \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} \right)^2  = 9 \\ &\Longrightarrow \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2 + 2 \cdot \frac{x}{y} \cdot  \frac{y}{x} + \left( \frac{y}{x} \right)^2 = 9 \\ &\Longrightarrow \frac{x^2}{y^2} + \frac{y^2}{x^2} = 9-2=7. \end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Start by squaring both sides of $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}=3$. What happens to the cross terms?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Look at:

$$\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}\right)^2=3^2=9$$

Why to look at this? We know if we expand we will have a $(\frac{x}{y})^2=\frac{x^2}{y^2}$ term and a $(\frac{y}{x})^2=\frac{y^2}{x^2}$ term so this might be worth a try.